# How to synchronously execute when using wait() function in Android?

Tags: java, android

While executing the following code in an Android App, the setText happens after mainActivity.notify() is called from another Service. So, it appears as if the mainActivity.wait() is getting executed before the setText, resulting in the setText getting waited.

What may be the reason for this and how to make the Toast execute before mainActivity.wait(), so that the setText is displayed while the MainActivity waits.

```
public static Activity mainActivity;
....
startButton.setText("Processing...");
synchronized(MainActivity.mainActivity) {
                try {
                    mainActivity.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
startButton.setText("Start");
```

Comment: Are you freezing the UI thread? Why?

Comment: You cannot cause the main (UI) thread to wait. There is no reason for this and the Android framework will not permit it. It will kill your app for being non-responsive. What are  you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @DavidWasser I understand that. My MainActivity is waiting just for 1-2 seconds till the service completes processing so that it can display the results that the Service generates.

Comment: @cricket_007 My MainActivity is waiting just for 1-2 seconds till the service completes processing so that it can display the results that the Service generates.

Comment: How do you know it's waiting that long? Are you manually sleeping the thread?

Comment: @cricket_007 No, the Service is actually recording a 6-minute sound file and takes a couple of seconds to process soundRecorder.stopSoundRecording() [it seems that creating a file from the recording takes a couple of seconds].

Comment: Basically, @Gabe's answer covers it. Your approach is wrong. If you want to show something while waiting, show a progress Dialog. When the `Service` has done its work, it can send an `Intent`. or call a method in your `Activity` that will then dismiss the progress Dialog. You absolutely positively cannot block the main (UI) thread for any length of time, ever. This stops everything, including showing `Toast`s.

Comment: @DavidWasser Point taken, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, never have a static reference to an Activity.  That's an almost assured memory leak.  If you think you need that, your entire app's architecture is almost certainly wrong, or you don't understand how to use Contexts.

Secondly, under the hood Android, like any other GUI OS, is driven by an event loop.  By holding up the main thread, you prevent the event loop from executing thus freezing the entire app.  In particular without running the event loop the application will never redraw.

Third, you cannot wait until a Toast appears.  Toasts are displayed by the system itself, and it does so when it decides to-  there may be other toasts on screen already, for example.  There is no mechanism to be informed of when a toast is displayed.  The purpose of a toast is fire and forget, if you need something more powerful you'll need to write it yourself.

Comment: 1st: I will try to learn more and remove that.

2nd: My MainActivity is waiting just for 1-2 seconds till the service completes processing so that it can display the results that the Service generates.

3rd: I knew that for a Toast. But other things like changing text on a button is also behaving similarly [executes after notify() is called even though it is written before wait()].

Comment: Using wait and notify to wait for a service to finish is wrong. Services use the same thread so it will never happen. If you need to be notified of a service finishing computations, use a bound service and callback. You should never be waiting on the main thread in android (or any other gui based framework)

Comment: Thanks. That is why, I am doing the processing by creating another thread inside the service. I will look into the methods suggested by you and try to implement as you said. However, what surprises is why is the execution not synchronous. When I have called setText before wait(), why does it get executed after notify() is called from within the Service.

Comment: Because the app doesn't redraw until the event loop processes the next event. Which doesn't happen until the main thread returns to the event loop from whatever function in your app was called. Set text is being called when you call it, but the results aren't on screen until the next redraw

Answer (score -4):

You can use Thread.sleep method

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);         
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```